# Access root file file from public folder in express.js

Tags: node.js, express

I want to access config folder files inside from a js file that is in public folder.But I am unable to link the file that is in config folder from a file in public folder.Is there any way to access the file.

[image]

Comment: Don't do that! If you could read it from the public folder, everyone can do that! If you need info from a config file, do an API from the backend and ask that info to it.

Comment: Can you suggest the best practise to use where to put all the config directory so that it can be access from both server side and client side ?